# Como valido un formulario con un procedimiento almacenado en .net

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Tengo un formulario en .net visual studio pero quier validar la existencia de algunos datos antes de ingresarlos, por ejemplo si un nombre ya se encuentra en la base, entonces que mande un mensaje que no se puede porque ya existe.

Lo que realize es algo asi:

```
protected void btn_agregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cls_Jugador _jugador = new Cls_Jugador(Convert.ToInt32(dl_lista_provincia.SelectedValue),
                    Convert.ToInt32(dl_lista_cantones.SelectedValue),Convert.ToInt32(dl_lista_distritos.SelectedValue));
            _jugador.NumeroCedula = txt_cedula.Text;
            if (rb_masculino.Checked == true)
            {
                _jugador.Genero = "M";
            }
            else
            {
                _jugador.Genero = "F";
            }
            _jugador.FechaNacimiento = txt_fecha_nacimiento.Text;
            _jugador.NumeroTelefono = txt_telefono.Text;
            _jugador.Correo = txt_correo.Text;
            _jugador.Nombre = txt_nombre.Text;
            _jugador.Apellido1 = txt_apellido1.Text;
            _jugador.Apellido2 = txt_apellido2.Text;
            _jugador.DireccionCasa = txt_direccion.Value;

            //HACEMOS LA VALIDACION SI SE REGISTRP EL JUGADOR
            switch (_jugador.pc_registrar_jugador())
            {

                case -100:
                    lbl_mensaje.Text = "Ocurrio un error";
                    break;
                default:
                    lbl_mensaje.Text = "Jugador registrado";
                    break;
            }


        }
```

Comment: Que has intentado? Por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Asumo que, por el tag, estás utilizando Entity Framework. Si suponemos que estás creando la entidad con decoradores en las clases, entonces, convendría crear una llave única para el nombre del jugador:

```
public class Cls_Jugador 
{
    // otras propiedades
    [Index("IX_NombreJugador", IsUnique = true)]
    public string Nombre {get;set;}
}
```

Si necesitas que la llave sea compuesta, es decir, necesitas que la combinación "Nombre y Apellido" sean únicas, entonces, puedes intentar esto:

```
public class Cls_Jugador 
{
    // otras propiedades
    [Index("IX_NombreJugador", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Nombre {get;set;}

    [Index("IX_NombreJugador", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Apellido1 {get;set;}
}
```

Lamentablemente no especificas qué hace el método

```
_jugador.pc_registrar_jugador()
```

Pero, si lo estás haciendo a través de EF, entonces, deberás tener un try-catch, y en el catch revisar si la excepción es de tipo SqlException:

```
try
{
   // otras validaciones
   dbContext.Jugadores.Add(jugador);
   dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (UniqueConstraintException e)
{
    // El Constraint fue violado. 
    // Realizar las tareas correspondientes. Podrías dar return -100 aquí.
    // O únicamente enviar el mensaje.
    return "El jugador ya fue registrado anteriormente";

}
```

Podrías, si quisieras, realizar una búsqueda antes, a través del nombre del jugador para verificar si existe:

```
// otras validaciones
var existe = dbContext.Jugadores.Where(x=> x.Nombre.Equals(_jugador)).FirstOrDefault();
// FirstOrDefault() devuelve la entidad si existe, de lo contrario devuelve null.

if(existe != null)
{
   // El jugador existe y deberás manejar el caso.
}
// el jugador no existe y se puede registrar:
pc_registrar_jugador();
```

Con la información que provees, que tal vez no sea mucha, es lo mejor que podemos hacer. Espero te  ponga en el camino correcto.

**Edit:**
Si en realidad insistes en utilizar un procedimiento almacenado, entonces, deberás crearlo primero

```
create proc dbo.JugadorVerificarNombreUnico (@nvarchar(50) NombreJugador)
as
Begin
Select Nombre 
  from dbo.Jugador 
 where Nombre = @NombreJugador
End
```

Este procedimiento deberás llamarlo desde el código de esta manera:

```
using (var context = new NombreDeTuContext())
{
    var parametro = new SqlParameter("@Nombre", SqlDbType.NVarChar){
                                Value=_jugador.Nombre)}
    var existeJugador = context.Database
                        SqlQuery<Cls_Jugador>("dbo.JugadorVerificarNombreUnico", parametro).FirstOrDefault();

   //luego la validación es la misma. Actuarás si existe o no.
   if(existeJugador==null)
  // etc....

  }
```